# Как увидеть реальный размер базы данных?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Добрый вечер мне нужно хранить примерно 30к строк, и меня интересует как бд на 30000 строк весит столько же сколько и бд но без записей. Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот примерное наполнение таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообщем просто набор букв для таблицы.

И как узнать реальный вес бд/таблицы?

Comment: При создании БД сразу выделяется некоторое количество памяти для будущего использования. [File Space Management](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-space.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак я нашел как посмотреть вес mysql таблиц. Все очень просто (идем путем поиска и взвешивания файлов ).

1. Узнаем где храняться все файлы бд и таблиц.

```
grep datadir /etc/my.cnf
```

или

```
grep -r datadir /etc/mysql/
```

Вот что вы получите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Переходим в директорию после знака = :

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
```

3. Что бы получить вес таблицы мы переходим в папку с названием нашей базы данных и что бы в приятном виде мы увидели вес файлов нужно ввести:

```
ls -lh
```

Вы увидете примерно такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также что бы видеть размер в МегаБайтах можно добавить аргумент
`--block-size=MB`
Пример:

```
ls -lh --block-size=MB
```

Вот и все мы видим вес любой таблицы.

Comment: [man du](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если нет доступа к самом серверу (к файловой системе), можно попробовать узнать размер сделав SQL запрос:

```
SELECT table_schema "DB Name",
ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Или не применять округление и получить точный размер в байтах

Comment: Вот это крутой ответ! а то по файловой системе то полазить - каждый может!